# Style MySQL Output in PHP with CSS

Tags: php, css, mysql

I have a MySQL Database and it prints live ne activities with PHP on my website. Now I like to style these text outputs (color, position, size) but I don't know how. Do you have any ideas?

```js
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=x.x.x.x.x;dbname=x.x.x.x', 'x.x.x.x', 'x.x.x.x');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo '<span class="temperature">' . $row['temperatur'] . '</span>';
   echo '<span class="unit">°C</span>';
}
?>

<style>
.temperature {
    color: red;
}

.unit {
    color: blue;
    margin-top: 2em;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

The first question/issue is solved!

Second question: I like to margin-top the img but it does not work. The height and width worked well but margin-top has no effect. Does anyone have an idea?

```js
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row)
        if ($row['status'] == '1') {
    $image = "alarm";}
        else {
    $image = "noalarm";}

    echo '<img src="img/' . $image . '.png" margin-top="3.5em" height="40%" width="35%" title="Fire" alt="Fire" />';
?>
```

Comment: wrap them in a span with a class and style the class like normal - eg `echo "<span class=\"temp\">".$row['temperatur']." °C</span>";`

Comment: You inject HTML and style with CSS before `echo`, take a look at w3school, they already have examples.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any problem in writing CSS styles like in other use cases?

Comment: How would you have styled the _text content_ “Foo” in any static HTMNL document …? Answering that, would also answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your PHP output in HTML, then you can style it as you would any other HTML element.

```
<?php
//Database connection//

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo '<span class="temperature">' . $row['temperatur'] . '</span>';
   echo '<span class="unit">°C</span>';
}
?>
```

CSS

```
.temperature {
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
}

.unit {
    display: inline-block;
    color: blue;
}
```

**Edit ----------**

Please try the above code exactly. Including the CSS. It looks like your CSS may be throwing off your display, as from a PHP perspective, this should work.

Here's an example of it working in PHP playground: https://www.tehplayground.com/0aSiTkueB3pS1Fl4

Comment: Have you checked to see you're actually getting a value at `$row['temperatur']` ? `var_dump($row)` will help...

Comment: Have you a `. temperature` CSS class somewhere that could be overriding it?

Comment: No, I have also tried a really unique class but it won't work. The unit styling works well.

Comment: That `foreach()` needs some  `{}`

Comment: Can you edit your question with your *exact* code for this.... I feel like this is a typo somewhere.

Comment: ^^^ That's likely it. I forgot the `{ }` when switching it to multiple `echo`s ‍♂️

Comment: It is my exact code for this output. I print the output in my .html file with this
`<?php include ("php/dht22_wohnzimmer_temp.php"); ?>` 
I have tried the `{}` but with these it doesn't show the `[temperatur]` and the `°C`. :(

Comment: Can you *edit your question* with the contents of `dht22_wohnzimmer_temp.php` (just the bit containing the snippet will do....). We can't see where the problem lies without seeing the code.

Comment: I have edited it and now you can see my actual code.

Comment: See my edit. I suspect your CSS is the problem, not the PHP. Check out: https://www.tehplayground.com/0aSiTkueB3pS1Fl4

Comment: Hi Prettyfly. I have a second question - if you like and have time, you can check it maybe. I added it under my existing question. Thank you :)

Comment: First, don't use inline styling, create a css class for the image. Second, apply `display: block;` to it, otherwise it's treated as an inline element, so margins won't work properly.